# Delay rendering UI until store loads in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, rendering, store

The store I want to load takes significant time in authentication and fetching the data (huge), and  I need to select one field from store as default as per the condition. Since the store takes a lot of time (8-10s) and UI is rendered already, so setting the value appears out of nowhere, which is annoying.

My store is defined as:

```
var profileStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: 'profileStore ',
        method: 'GET',
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: url,
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                name: 'name',
                fields: 'fields'
            })
        })
    });
```

and the load happens as follows:

```
profileStoreData = profileStore.load({
            callback: function(cmp) {
               //logic for setting default field
            }
        });
viewModel.set('profileStoreStored', profileStoreData);
```

what can I do to delay rendering UI until this logic is executed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can manually load all required data within [Ext.app.Application](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.app.Application.html) [`init()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.app.Application.html#method-init) method

> A template method that is called when your application boots. It is called before the Ext.app.Application's launch function is executed so gives a hook point to run any code before your Viewport is created.

via asynchronous ajax request (using [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Ajax.html) [`requiest()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Ajax.html#method-request) method with `async: false` option) and load data into your store manually.

*In my application while loading all necessary data I use mask with "Loading ..." text and remove it within Ext.app.Application `init()` when all preparations finished.*